# Can we ask about MUDs, based on specific Tabletop systems?

Tags: discussion, questions

Okay, the title to this doesn't quite well define the question but it's as close as I could get it.

I was going to post a question in the parent site, until stopped to realize that it is probably *really* stretching the realm of relevancy.  So, I'm throwing it here to be judged and will drop it on the parent if it passes muster.

"Are there any MUDs based on D&D 4th Edition?"

That's it.  I'm not looking to ask a question about any particular MUD, or how to run or play a MUD.  I just want to ask if there are any that are specifically designed to emulate my favorite tabletop system.

I would almost dare say this is similar enough to another fairly well-received (if only lukewarmly welcomed) question I've posted, regarding [tabletop RPGs featured in non-gaming media](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/4251/197), that it should be accepted.  But, I'm leaving it up here for the community to decide.

Thoughts, anyone?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I wouldn't.

It opens the door to all kinds of things *based on* specific tabletop systems. Are there any coloring books based on D&D? (yes)

Also, I don't know if this community is the right one to answer those questions. Do we have the expertise?

The question you use as an example ("[What non-gaming media can provide outsiders a good example of tabletop RPGs?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/4251/what-non-gaming-media-can-provide-outsiders-a-good-example-of-tabletop-rpgs)") is actually focused on the tabletop RPG experience. It asks, how do we better bring outsiders into that experience?

The MUD question is actually focused on a non-tabletop RPG experience. It asks, how do we find a particular kind of computer game (tangentially related to our tabletop RPG experience)?

Comment: You make a good distinction here, Adam.  Thanks.

Comment: I'd say that asking at Gaming.SE would actually be *practically* better. Just because we know RPGs doesn't mean we know MUDs, let alone the current crop available. Conversely, people at Gaming.SE will know MUDs intimately, and don't need to be RPG experts to say, "Oh yeah, I noticed one the other day pop up on my 'New MUD of the Day' bloggertubes feed. Here it is. What's D&D anyway?"

Answer (score 0):

No. For the same reason we don't [discuss board games based on RPGs](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/284/are-questions-about-role-playing-derivative-board-games-off-topic).

Comment: You seem to be totally missing the point in my question, that the question is not about any specific RPG-based non-tabletop game.  Instead, it's asking "Where can I find the mechanics of [system x] implemented in [media y]."