# Where to ask about a game that straddles the line?

Tags: discussion, on-topic

I have fond memories of Wizards, by Avalon Hill. To me it's basically an RPG - your characters have stats and levels, roll dice for random encounters, etc. It has some issues, though, so I want to adjust the rules to make it more appealing to my pals.

If I said it was a board game, I probably wouldn't get much argument as there is a board involved. However, the specific question I want to ask SE involves homebrewing the rules to differentiate the spellcasting classes more, which seems like a topic people here would be better suited to answer. What's my best option here?

Comment: Many board games may feel like roleplaying games, or academically look like one (a debate rages over whether Monopoly can be considered a roleplaying game - you *can* roleplay in it), but that doesn't make them count effectively as the type of RPG we handle.

Comment: You might find this question useful: [What's the difference between a roleplaying game and a board game?](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/20149/whats-the-difference-between-a-roleplaying-game-and-a-board-game)

Comment: How about tabletop wargames? Is D&D Battlesystem fair game?

Comment: @Michael Highly unlikely: http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/6005/are-table-top-battle-games-acceptable/6006#6006

Comment: Thanks for the super clear answer @SirTechSpec - awesome user name BTW :-D

Answer (score 13):

[*Wizards*](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/828/wizards) is unambiguously a board game. (A very cool looking board game!) It's not unlike more recent examples of games that contain elements that look like RPG elements, such as [*Descent*](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/104162/descent-journeys-dark-second-edition), [*Mice and Mystics*](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/124708/mice-and-mystics), and [*Dungeons & Dragons: Castle Ravenloft Board Game*](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/59946/dungeons-dragons-castle-ravenloft-board-game)<sup>1</sup>, which are definitely board games despite passing resemblances.

The place to ask about house rules for *Wizards* would be:

- [Board and Card Games SE](http://boardgames.stackexchange.com), where they have [a tag for house rules](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/house-rules).

  It may be hard to ask an SE-appropriate question for what you're looking for though, as it may be more on the idea-generation side. In that case you might try…
- The forums attached to the [BoardGameGeek listing for *Wizards*](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/828/wizards).

<sup>1. *Castle Ravenloft* and its kin have specifically been discussed before on meta: [Are questions about role-playing derivative board games on topic?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/284/are-questions-about-role-playing-derivative-board-games-on-topic)</sup>